# Find file and execute for each find

Tags: windows, command-line

From the windows command line - I want to find a particular type of exe (e.g. foo.exe) in a drive (say c) and then execute it with some parameter (e.g. foo.exe -parameter). The following command

```
    dir c:\abcd.exe /s/b
```

finds all the occurrence of foo.exe in the drive (incl all sub-directories) for me and reports with full path.

How do I use something like for or foreach or pipe on the command line along-with the dir statement as above to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `for /?` on the command line. And maybe `call /?` if needed.

This should give you insight on something like this:

```
for "usebackq" /f %%i in (`dir c:\abcd.exe /s /b`) do (
  call "%%i" -parameter
)
```

The %%i is a place holder you can use inside the for loop to denote the current line of the output from the dir command. I added the `call` because I assume that you would want the loop to iterate through all the lines from the `dir` output. If you want to stop after the first hit, just leave out the `call` statement. Program flow will then be passed to the exe file and all subsequent lines in the batch file won't be executed.

HTH. GL, HF :)